# What is the difference between "I am able to" and "I can"?

Tags: ambiguity

Please, tell me the difference between these two statements.

Comment: Saeid, when you are ready, click the tick-mark below the score of the answer you want to accept. You can also upvote the answer if it's actually been useful.

Answer (score 6):

*Able to* technically describes your **ability** to do something, while *can* means that you are not only capable of doing a certain action, but also that you are **allowed** to do such an action.

Imagine the following case:

> I can swim.

This means that you know how to swim and also you are allowed to go to the pool and swim. Your parents are OK with it.

versus

> I am able to swim.

This means that you know how to swim, but doesn't further specify whether you are allowed to swim. Maybe you are not. Maybe your parents did not allow you to, because they are worried you'd drown.

Therefore, a great sentence would be:

> I am able to kill a man, but I can't do it.